# Pass Swift Array to Objective-C Class as NSArray

Tags: objective-c, swift

The method I'm calling is defined in Objective C as:

```
@interface F53OSCMessage : F53OSCPacket <NSCoding, NSCopying>
{
    NSString *_addressPattern;
    NSString *_typeTagString;
    NSArray *_arguments;
    id _userData;
}
```

I'm trying to pass this variable to it from Swift:

```
var test = [1, 2, "string"];
```

I've tried doing it like this:

```
var message = F53OSCMessage(addressPattern: endpoint, arguments: test);
```

and

```
var message = F53OSCMessage(addressPattern: endpoint, arguments: test as NSArray!);
```

But when I do that I get the error:

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'F53OSCMessage' that accepts an argument list of type '(addressPattern: String, arguments: NSArray!)'

So then I tried (as per Xcode's suggestion):

```
var message = F53OSCMessage(addressPattern: endpoint, arguments: args as [AnyObject]!);
```

But that gives me several Apple Macho-O Linker errors:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_F53OSCClient", referenced from:
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea what's going on? I'm confused as to why Xcode wants an [AnyObject] even though the method defines `_arguments` as an NSArray. Calling the method like this works, which just makes me even more confused.

```
var message = F53OSCMessage(addressPattern: endpoint, arguments: "");
```

Comment: "But that gives me several Apple Macho-O Linker errors" – not, **it's not the change in question that results in linker errors.** The change **fixes** your code *so that it compiles.* The fact that it doesn't *link* means that you aren't linking your final executable with the object file that contains the `F53OSCClient` class.

Comment: As per Xcode's suggestion, what it is expecting for parameter arguments: ?

Comment: @Amit89 Xcode is expecting `F53OSCMessage(addressPattern: <#String!#>, arguments: <#[AnyObject]!#>)`

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant what do I do to fix that problem?

Comment: @Alfo which problem?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant that the final executable isn't being linked with the object file? It's imported (so that Xcode autocomplete works) and added to the target

Comment: @Alfo maybe Xcode is having a hiccup and doesn't the linker all the object files? Try a "clean project"… but I'm not really sure – I don't use Xcode, I compile my code from the command line (exactly for this reason and similar ones – I like to know what's happening – stuff's easier to debug that way.)

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue.

```
var test:[AnyObject] = [1, 2, "string"];
var endpoint = "www.abc.com"
var message = F53OSCMessage(addressPattern: endpoint, arguments: test);
```